# ImmutableMap.of() workaround for HashMap in Maps?

Tags: java, collections, guava

There are utility methods to create `ImmutableMap` like `Immutable.of(Key, value)` and its overload. 
But such methods don't exist for `HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap` in `Maps` class. 
Is there any better way to do this or Guava assumes such a map is always a constant map and `ImmutableMap` is best option to go with and don't need to provide a utility for `HashMap`.

Comment: Collections.singletonMap

Comment: he's asking for a mutable map, and to support more than just one entry.

Comment: @kevin, you mean a mutable map w/ just one entry, what's exactly the point of? If you imply a general hashmap, you'd be better off initializing it w/ the expected capacity than just a single key-value (which makes little to no sense to me)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why would you want those for a regular `HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap`? You can just do this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = Maps.newHashMap();
map.put(key, value);
```

The thing with `ImmutableMap` is that it is a little bit more cumbersome to create; you first need to make a `Builder`, then put the key-value pairs in the builder and then call `build()` on it to create your `ImmutableMap`. The `ImmutableMap.of()` method makes it shorter to write if you want to create an `ImmutableMap` with a single key-value pair.

Consider what you'd have to write if you wouldn't use the `ImmutableMap.of()` method:

```
ImmutableMap<String, Object> map = ImmutableMap.builder()
    .put(key, value);
    .build();
```

Comment: @Jasper - If I'm not mistaken support to create a Map like Map<String, Integer> map = {"key" : 1}; will be added in java 8.. if it sounds good then why not have such utilities

Comment: @Falcon Yes, support for collection literals is one of the features that has been proposed for Java 8. This will mainly be useful for "fixed" maps, for example for a map that you initialize once and then never change the content. But for that purpose you should be using `ImmutableMap` if you're using Guava, instead of a regular mutable `HashMap`.

Comment: Java 8?:) I believe it will be similar to Java 7 - overdue and overpromising:)...

Comment: @Gabriel Java 7 is coming out this summer (end of July) and collection literals will unfortunately not be in there... Java 8 is planned for the end of 2012.

Comment: I know, if everything was according to plans, we would have Java 7 already here with lambdas...

Comment: ImmutableMap.copyOf(new HashMap<String, Long>());

Comment: ImmutableMap doesn't support `null` values.

Answer (score 17):

Try `Maps.newHashMap(ImmutableMap.of(...))`

[`Maps.newHashMap(Map map)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMap(java.util.Map))

Comment: I see two `newHashMap` methods on that page: one takes no arguments at all and the other takes a `Map`. Which one of those would your code call?

Comment: Ok, `Maps.newHashMap(ImmutableMap.of(...))` is short to write, but it's not very efficient: you're first creating an `ImmutableMap` and then you copy its contents to a regular `HashMap`, and then throw the temporary `ImmutableMap` away...

Comment: Beware that this also denies `null` keys and values.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is that for an immutable map, you *have* to provide everything up-front, because you can't change it after construction. For mutable maps, you can just create the map and then add the entries. Admittedly this makes it slightly harder to create a map in a single expression, but that doesn't *tend* to be a problem where you'd want a mutable map anyway, in my experience.

Comment: You can create a mutable map and expose only the non-mutable interface. (The underlying map is still mutable)

Comment: @bestsss: You can do so, yes... but I'd say it's relatively rare that you want to do that *and* initialize it in a single expression.

Comment: sure, yet I guess it depends what people assume as single expression. A function that takes an Object[][] or Object[], Object[] can do so, and many developers would praise it for being cool.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken support to create a Map like Map<String, Integer> map = {"key" : 1}; will be added in java 8.. if it sounds good then why not have such utilities

Comment: @Falcon, the generics made java harder to parse/read (just imagine the case when you have class name clashes). It's relatively rare (like Jon implies) you need to create a map by a single expression, it's doable now and I see no reason to 'improve' the language. Only configurations come to me as truly usable scenario and I prefer to keep them in xml.

Answer (score 5):

cannot you use the `copyOf` method of `ImmutableMap` described [here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#copyOf-java.util.Map-)?

it should be something like

```
Map newImmutableMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(yourMap);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ImmutableMap.of()` returns a hash based immutable map without order.

If you need ordered immutable map, `ImmutableSortedMap.of()` is a choice.

ImmutableSortedMap provides methods such as `firstKey()`, `lastKey()`, `headMap(K)` and `tailMap(K)`;

Both classes provide `copyOf(Map)` method.