# Java - The best way to store configs inside a program

Tags: java, xml, config

I have an XML file, which contains rules for code analyzer (to search vulnerabilities). So, it has very different rules like parameter, parameter count, any parameter type, const value and etc for method call (to detect specific calls), rules to detect some imports, inheritance and so on. But how to store this inside my program?
I found two ways:

1. Parse xml while scanning (to internal representation)
2. Create classes for each element: parameter, parameter value, number of
   parameters

Is there a real life example of implementing this thing? Or you may just say the best/common way to do this

Comment: Feel free to ask something and comment, I will alter the question

Comment: What would be the reason to keep it in the code? In this case you can't move between environments dev/test/prod - you will need to change code. Keep config in xml file in the same repository and use it as resource.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in XML file will probably be the easiest method

Comment: But it will require me to write more duplicate code. Just imagine: different rules for different tasks. I also want to add Conditions which will contain logical operators

Comment: XML is the most common way I know of to store configs. The conditions will most likely be handled in java code. You may have to write more duplicate code but following a common methodology you are not killing how maintainable your code is

Comment: You are right, but I was planning to make a kind of AST (tokens are my final rules which are not NOT, OR, AND logical operators), isn't that so good?

Comment: can you not read from the xml file and create your AST off of that? Then you can reuse any applicable trees to reduce duplicated code

Comment: DId this help? Any more questions? If yes, I'd love to try to answer them if not please accept

Comment: Yes. Having AST means I will have internal representation, this is not the same with parsing XML

Answer (score 0):

If you like to keep config in your code - use code to do so. Here is good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261075/adding-multiple-entries-to-a-hashmap-at-once-in-one-statement) of simple initialization:

```
Map<String, Integer> config = new HashMap<String, Integer>()
{{
     put("One", 1);
     put("Two", 2);
     put("Three", 3);
}};
```

Comment: But what is that? How HashMap can help me with storing configs?

Comment: You didn't provide any example. I assumed it's simple key=value pairs. If it is not then xml is the only option. And I'll quote myself " Keep config in xml file in the same repository and use it as resource"

Answer (score 0):

To this cases i love to use properties files

> .properties is a file extension for files mainly used in Java related technologies to store the configurable parameters of an application. They can also be used for storing strings for Internationalization and localization; these are known as Property Resource Bundles.

Suppose you have a file in your package path.to.your with a properties file file.properties you can include them in you jar and recover the file with `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/your/file.properties")` then you can load the bundle, change the params, add new keys, etc, more info with [MKYong - Java Properties file examples](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)