# Java: How to convert a list to HashMap (key being the list) in one line

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8, hashmap

I have an arraylist of Strings:

```
ArrayList<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
```

I would like to initialize a map `HashMap<String, List<Integer>>` with the element of my list being the key and an empty list of integers being the value.

Of course there is a way to do it using a loop, but I wonder whether there is a way to do it in one line. After seeing the questions and answers in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261075/adding-multiple-entries-to-a-hashmap-at-once-in-one-statement), I am aware that it is doable by:

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> bigMap = ImmutableMap.<String, List<Integer>>builder()
.put("A", new ArrayList<Integer>)
.put("B", new ArrayList<Integer>)
.put("C", new ArrayList<Integer>)
.put("D", new ArrayList<Integer>)
.build();
```

But that only applies to the scenario that the size of the list is small. How can I do it using stream, like the way mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138364/java-how-to-convert-list-to-map)?

Comment: Did you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20887747/1746118) from the linked question? Could you explain what your question above that is?

Comment: @Naman yes but that answer gives an example where it maps to the value, not the key, and it uses function `getKey` as the key which is different from what I have.

Comment: The question you've asked about is using streams, the answer linked shares an approach of doing that. In your case, constant value in the map as the value works instead, `e -> Collections.emptyList()`. Just give it a try at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Collectors.toMap()`:

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> bigMap =
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),e-> new ArrayList<Integer>()));
```

Comment: or `e -> Collections.emptyList()` if that's better read.

Comment: @Naman That would populate the `Map` with immutable empty `List`s. If the OP doesn't want to add elements to those `List`s, why create this `Map` in the first place?

Comment: I thought the question focussed on immutability from the sample code `ImmutableMap.<String, List<Integer>>builder`. Anyway, what you said makes sense for the actual use cases.