# The best way to static initialization of Maps in google collections

Tags: java, guava

What is the best way to static initialization of modifiable Maps? I found only

```
ImmutableMap.of(K k1, V v1, K k2, V v2, K k3, V v3, K k4, V v4, K k5, V v5)
```

But this way created immutable map and contains fixed list of parameters.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947869/like-immutablemap-of-for-hashmap-in-maps

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you do want an `of` code fashion, you could use:

```
myMap = Maps.newHashMap(ImmutableMap.of(k1, v1, k2, v2...));
```

In addition, `ImmutableMap.Builder` is other choice to create a Map from complex source:

```
myMap = Maps.newHashMap(new ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>()
                   .put(k1, v1) //One k-v pair 
                   .putAll(otherMap) //From other Map
                   .put(Maps.immutableEntry(k2, v3)) //From a Map Entry
                   ...
                   .build());
```

Plus: My code is not original intention of ImmutableMap. If Nawa insists on using Guava library ;)

Comment: That's a bit wasteful on the garbage creation front, though. In the first case, you create a temporary `ImmutableMap` whenever you want to create a `HashMap`, and in the second case, you create an `ImmutableMap.Builder` (which contains a mutable `Map`), which then creates an `ImmutableMap` before finally creating the `HashMap`...

Comment: @FrankPavageau Yes, you are right. My code is not original intention of ImmutableMap. I mean if Nawa insists on using Guava library ;)

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need static initialization. What's wrong with the following ?

```java
Map<K, V> map = Maps.newHashMap();
map.put(k1, v1);
map.put(k2, v2);
// More put() calls

// map is now ready to use.
```

You can create a helper method around it if needed, but you can only create so many different versions (for 1 entry, 2 entries, etc.). At some point it's not helping anymore.

Comment: Well, no. Either you write a static method for each number of entries you want to initialize the `Map` with, or you write a static method taking `Object[]` or `Object...` as a parameter and make sure its length is a multiple of 2 (to get an integer number of entries), but then you lose any type checking. I say stick with the sequence of `put()`s.

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in having this for mutable collections. The only reason I can think of is that you want to have a shorthand for this when creating initially small mutable maps. Write your own utility methods if you need this quiet often:

```
public static <K,V> HashMap<K,V> newHashMap(K k1, V v1) {
    HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(k1, v1);
    return map;
}

public static <K,V> HashMap<K,V> newHashMap(K k1, V v1, K k2, V v2) {
    HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(k1, v1);
    map.put(k2, v2);
    return map;
}

...
```

Override it as long as you think it is still readable. Because of mixture from keys and values this gets unreadable fast in my opinion - even with proper formatting.
Guava guys stopped this at 5 key-value pairs what is too much imho.